# How to call .hmtl file inside the header.php in wordpress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have finish all my html pages and now I want to add them inside the header.php.

Please see the code below:

```
<li class="menu-item">  <a href="<?php the_permalink('/aboutus.html'); ?>"> AboutUs</a> </li>
```

As you can see Iam using the_permalink function to call the html file , but when I click in the navbar the aboutus nothing happen , I dont get the aboutus.html.

Can you please tell me how to ge to my point?

Comment: If your .html file is in the root of your site (eg. `/public_html/aboutus.html`) then you don't need to use the `the_permalink()` function at all. All you'd need is this: `href="./aboutus.html"`. On the other hand, if you're trying to integrate your custom HTML template into WordPress then it might be a good idea to review the [Theme Developer Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/) to learn how to do so properly.

Comment: It makes no sense whatsoever to try and use `the_permalink` here - that is for post living in your database, that have a slug defined there. Your static HTML page has nothing whatsoever to do with that.

Comment: thank you very much for your help it works $location_of_file .'/aboutus.html'

Answer (score 1):

You do not output anything from PHP. Change `<?php`  to `<?=`:

```html
<li class="menu-item">  <a href="<?= the_permalink('/aboutus.html'); ?>"> AboutUs</a> </li>
```

Comment: Even if it was a valid solution (which it isn't), OP should be using [get_permalink()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/) and not [the_permalink()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_permalink/).

Comment: Doesn't change the fact that using `the_permalink` makes no sense here to begin with. That function wants a post id or a post object as parameter. The mere name of a static HTML file placed somewhere in the file system, has absolutely nothing whatsoever to do with this.

Comment: @cabrerahector no, OP should use neither.

Comment: I know, hence why I said "it isn't" (a valid solution) @CBroe. I'll edit my initial comment to make it more clear.

Comment: Well, I took too long to edit the initial comment haha. So here: even if this was a valid solution (which it isn't), OP would need to use [get_permalink()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/) and not [the_permalink()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_permalink/). But, again, OP isn't using the right methods to add their HTML template into the site. Check Cbroe's and my comments under the original question for more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
<li class="menu-item">  <a href="<?php echo $location_of_file .'/aboutus.html'; ?>"> AboutUs</a> </li>
```

$location_of_file will contain address to aboutus.html file without slash at the end.

Comment: thank you very much it works with $location_of_file

Comment: To do this in wordpress way you can add template name in php file and publish a page using that template name.